# COMPRESS (Transact-SQL) On Row Insert Using Spring Batch JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql , one should be able to compress data during the table insert. They even provide an example (below), which works just fine when you're running the query from a DB client (e.g., DBVis):

```
    INSERT INTO player (info )  
    VALUES (COMPRESS(N'{"sport":"Tennis","age": 28,"rank":1,"points":15258, turn":17}'));
```

What I'm trying to do is to use Spring Batch's JdbcBatchItemWriter's setSql method to insert/compress a String (String payload_compressed in the following example).

```
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Consol> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO foo (payload_compressed) VALUES (:payload_compressed)");
```

but have been failing miserably.

I just need to somehow modify the prepared statement so that I can write something similar to this:

```
    itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO foo (payload_compressed) VALUES (COMPRESS(N':payload_compressed'))");
```

I've even tried setting the *payload_compressed*  field into byte[] and compressing it using GZIP (which is SQL server supposedly using for the COMPRESS() function) before inserting it into the DB. It "worked" fine with the one problem that I was not able to use SQL Server's DECOMPRESS() function to pull and read the data back from the DB - i.e., I want to be able to query the compressed data directly from a DB client using the DECOMPRESS() function.

Any comments/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

** UPDATE **

The working solution - compressing/decompressing the String in Java without utilizing SQL Server's COMPRESS()/DECOMPRESS() - as follows:

To zip/unzip the data (https://gist.github.com/yfnick/227e0c12957a329ad138):

```
public class Gzip {

public static byte[] compress(String data) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length());
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
    gzip.write(data.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
    bos.close();
    return compressed;
}

public static String decompress(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    gis.close();
    bis.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Then the insert snippet (a very rough example):

```
public class Consol {
private byte[] payload_compressed;
..
}

 String payload = "{\"sport\":\"Tennis\",\"age\": 28,\"rank\":1,\"points\":15258, turn\":17}";

payload_compressed = Gzip.compress(payload)

JdbcBatchItemWriter<Consol> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
itemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO consol (payload_compressed) VALUES (:payload_compressed)");
```

On the SQL Server side, the "payload_compressed" column is set as follows:

```
payload_compressed VARBINARY(5000) NOT NULL
```

If I then read the data back and decompress it using the Gzip.decompress() util it is all well and happy. However, if I try to decompress the field directly with a qry in a DB client (DbViz, SQL Server Mgt Studio...) - just as an example:

```
select cast(decompress([payload_compressed]) as nvarchar(max)) as "payload_decompressed"
from dbo.consol
```

I get a decompressed CLOB, but it's all gibberish.

That being said, if I try to read a different field that was compressed using SQL Server's COMPRESS() function with the Gzip.decompress() method, it in fact returns the correct String which may suggest that the GZIP algorithm is the same; although there are additional blank spaces between all individual characters after decompression so am not sure that is because of the charset or some other reason... As an example, {"name":"Paul"} (compressed using SQL Server COMPRESS()) would return as { " n a m e " : " P a u l " } (decompressed using the Gzip util).

Regardless, even though this is a working solution, ultimately it means that no one can query the DB table directly from a client and everyone would need to go through Java and the GzipUtil, which is not necessarily ideal.

Comment: You mention that the insert “worked”. Great! Where is the code you’re using to read the data? That seems to be where the issue begins.

Comment: thanks for the note! I've added more details to the post - including how I read/query the data.